# proxy authentication with {RCurl}

Tags: r, curl, web

Being not an expert on `web-programming`, I attempt to automate a task which consists of getting into a website, download some `csv` files, and finally import them in R for data analysis.

In this context, I am working on the below sample code found on internet, which has been customized a bit to my need, and wonder to know more about the resulting error:

```
library(RCurl)
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiejar = 'cookies.txt', followlocation = TRUE, autoreferer = 
TRUE, curl = curl)

# Load the page for the first time to capture VIEWSTATE:

html <- getURL('https://www.olisnet.com/OlisAuthenticate/JSP/login.jsp',  
curl = curl, 
           .opts=list(ssl.verifypeer=FALSE))

# Extract VIEWSTATE with a regular expression or any other tool:

viewstate <- as.character(sub('.*id="__VIEWSTATE" value="([0-9a-zA-  
Z+/=]*).*', '\\1', html))

# Set the parameters as your username, password and the VIEWSTATE:

params <- list(
'user'         = '<USERNAME>',
'pass'         = '<PASSWORD>',
'__VIEWSTATE'                                  = viewstate
)

html = postForm('https://www.olisnet.com/OlisAuthenticate/JSP/login.jsp',   
.params = params, curl = curl,.opts=list(ssl.verifypeer=FALSE))     
 Error: Proxy Authentication Required

# Verify if you are logged in:
grepl('Logout', html)
[1]FALSE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach which worked for me :

```
library(RSelenium)

rd <- rsDriver(chromever = "105.0.5195.52", browser = "chrome", port = 4480L) 
remDr <- rd$client
remDr$open()
url <- "https://www.olisnet.com/OlisAuthenticate/JSP/login.jsp"
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj_Id <- remDr$findElement("id", "PIN")
web_Obj_Id$sendKeysToElement(list("myusername"))

web_Obj_First_GoButton <- remDr$findElement("id", "boutonGo")
web_Obj_First_GoButton$clickElement()

web_Obj_Password <- remDr$findElement("id", "PWD")
web_Obj_Password $sendKeysToElement(list("mypassword"))

web_Obj_Second_GoButton <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#form-step-2 > div > div > button")
web_Obj_Second_GoButton$clickElement()
```